# endless loop in a website - mod_rewrite

Tags: loops, infinite-loop, concrete5

I am getting an endless loop with a concrete5 site that just went live today... it was fine in development using a temporary URL, but now live only the homepage works... was wondering if this has something to do with pretty URLS.
error: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
Site is http://redletterdaysforbusiness.co.uk

Comment: It could be an issue with the rewrite rules, can the non-rewritten URLs still be accessed directly? Also, can you post the redirect rules you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed all was okay with the rewrite rules, and the error was in fact within C5 itself...
When developing the test site I had enabled pretty URLS, once I went live and changed the URL this didn't work anymore.
By disabling pretty URLS, all links worked. Then re-enabling prety URLS, everything still working.
Thanks jcem for you input.

Comment: How to access the dashboard then?